# Haskell: shortcut for type application

Tags: haskell

I have a call like `someFunc @'SomeX @'SomeY ...`. Is there some aliasing syntax to make it shorter? Something like:

```hs
type ??? = @'SomeX @'SomeY

someFunc @??? ...
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to. is even an at-sign without a preceding name valid code? consider writing a minimum working example, so it is easier to understand what you are going for

Comment: Do you have an example of providing the same `TypeApplications` to different functions? If it is the same function it would be easier to specialise it. This kind of alias is not possible in current Haskell without ridiculous machinery encoding type level functions. Even though I don't think this would be practically useful I think defining this language feature would be a fun exercise (what is the type of `???`).

Comment: @Iceland_jack it's a "method" of a type class.

Comment: Usually the type parameters are inferred by ghc so there is no actual need to provide them, if the types cannot be inferred from context then ideally it should be redesigned so that the compiler has enough information to make type applications unnecessary. A type class with associated type families can be made [injective](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_families.html#injective-type-families).

Comment: @LudvigH: This type of question asks how to express the desired semantics at all, so a working example with valid syntax is the desired *answer*. It could be clearer, but I think in this case it’s clear enough to be answerable. Given `f x y` and `g x y`, is there a way to factor out their common arguments `x y`, particularly when they’re type arguments `@'SomeX @'SomeY`? In fact this is a deep and fascinating question! In Haskell a solution *can* kinda be written in CPS, but *not* in “direct” style, because there are no “coterms” that could abstract over an application context like this.

Comment: Aha! so this is under -XTypeApplication ? then I follow the question. :) the extension was new to me. thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is very vague, but one thing you can do is to redefine `someFunc` with a more precise type:

```
someFunc :: a -> b -> a
someFunc x y = x

someFunc' :: Int -> Bool -> Int
someFunc' = someFunc
```

Then you can use `someFunc'` whenever you would previously write `someFunc @Int @Bool`.

Alternatively, if you only really care about that second `@'SomeY` argument, then you can use the snail: `someFunc @_ @'SomeY`. In this case the compiler will automatically try to fill in that underscore type application.